# Indentify Column From Last Non Zero Value in a Row and assign Month Value - POWER BI DAX. Average Consumption

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I need to average consumption over the period from the first order date (assuming 1st day of month) to Now (actual date). Consumption is totalled month by month over 12 months, the last month being the portion of the current month that has passe (ie today's date).

If I can identify the column (and thereby the month) that contains the first month an item was ordered, I can calculate the number of days since first order, and thereby calculate an average per day.

But I'm stumped!

I have a table with the headers: IDENTIFIER M12 M11 M10 M9 M8 M7 M6 M5 M4 M3 M2 M1

Identifier = Item Catalogue Number
M12 to M1 represent each month - M12 being current month, M1 being the first month.
Each month total has the total consumption per catalogue number in the columns.

Basically I need to find the number of days since the first consumption event for each row (item), and average the total over the number of days. If I can determine the first month, I can calculate the number of days and therefor the daily average.

[I have a stripped down example from Excel here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFFb.png)

In the accompanying image Yellow cells are guides to calculations and values (not part of table), Green cells are column headers, white cells are totals per month, Blue cells are the expected results (rounded up to whole number)

Eg Column M2 = 01/012/2022, M5 = 01/04/2023 etc

New column preferred with the result.

One way I've thought of is to identify the column that contains the first consumption, and add the date (ie Column M2 = 01/012/2022 in a special column - then calculation would be simple.

But I'm stumped at identifying the column!

Help greatly appreciated!